# Universal Property of Basis

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-linear space. $E\subseteq X$. Then $E$ is a basis of $X$ $\iff$ for every $\mathbb{K}$-linear space $Y$ and for every $f:E\rightarrow Y$, there exists a unique $\mathbb{K}$-linear extension $T:X\rightarrow Y$ of $f$.

Is the Hahn-Banach extension theorem is to be used? But I know it for only functional not for maps between spaces.

Comment: What type of basis? And is the extension continuous?

Comment: If $E$ is a basis then it is easy to construct the extension: whenever $x=\sum_i c_i x_i$ for basis elements $x_i$, $F(x)=\sum_i c_i F(x_i)$. It seems to me that the tricky part is the other direction.

Comment: Yes the extension is linear and continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{K}$-linear?  Do you mean a  vector space over $\mathbb{K}$? Or  a topological vector space?

Comment: @Theo $\mathbb{K}$ is the underlying field of the vector space.

Comment: This is true for vector spaces in general. It's essentially the universal property of free spaces. I'm not sure how this would work for topological vector spaces.